# "Incompatible type passed in as a parameter" error but only when value is above a certain number

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating computer generated math practice for my math students and trying to share the strategy with other math teachers. I've run into a bizarre programming issue. The issue is in that I need to use the same ID for both listbox and textbox. Neither will be present at the same time in the app, only one at a time when a new question is generated randomly. Here is a copy of the script file:
https://script.google.com/d/1GrswqbSU55vEzWD2V5dJyI95tBbFtNpn0OrnVK7FbbQVm5NpGvqhC_H5/edit?usp=sharing

And here is a version of the web app with the error present: 
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxfpZdZNNZWUU0KX-nicM27FtliatwCEkwOQ-bhTEu5LHLMDJo/exec

This code is from the generate question function:

```
else if(questionType == 4)
{ 
  if (a==0){a=a+1;}
  if (b==0){b=b+2;}
  if (c==0){c=c+3;}
//Listbox input  
var userInput = app.createListBox().addItem(a).addItem(eval(a-3)).setWidth(250).setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "24").setId('userInput').setName('userInput').setStyleAttribute('color', 'gray');

var correctAnswer = app.createTextBox().setName('correctAnswer').setId('correctAnswer');
var solution = eval(a-3);
correctAnswer.setValue(solution);
}
else if (questionType == 5)
{
  if (a==0){a=a+1;}
  if (b==0){b=b+2;}
  if (c==0){c=c+3;}
    //Textbox input
var userInput = app.createTextBox().setWidth(100).setStyleAttribute("fontSize", "24").setName('userInput').setStyleAttribute('color', 'gray').setValue('answer').setId('userInput');
var correctAnswer = app.createTextBox().setName('correctAnswer').setId('correctAnswer');
var solution = eval(a-c);
correctAnswer.setValue(solution);

}
```

What should I be doing when this function is called again to remove the last user input box from the app? It only gives me an error when the second question created is a different input type than the first.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Just make a proper answer (that is, not a comment), and then mark it as accepted (you may not be allowed to accept it given your low rep here).

Comment: Ok--thanks @HenriqueAbreu I updated my question above to reflect what I'm seeing the real issue is now too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error is coming from using the same id for a listbox and textbox. In the UiApp there is only one showing up at a time but whatever question type is generated first, say a textbox, the error comes when a question generated following is a listbox or visa versa. If all questions generated will be the same user input the error never happens (like if all questions gather user input through a listbox). I need the id to be the same for both for when the score question function is launched. 
I guess a follow up question would be how do I remove the remnants of the last input type from the app so the error stops happening? I've tried removing the user input by getElementById and it doesn't seem to work.